# Copy all items in a folder to another location

Tags: client-object-model

How do I copy all items from one folder(include sub folders and all files) to another folder or location?

I have to copy all items to one folder another folder by using C#

Comment: Here is an link with similar scenario [Copy folders when copying list items from source to destination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511694/copy-folders-when-copying-list-items-from-source-to-destination) Just change the code according to your need Hope it helps..

Comment: OP is asking about CSOM solution

Answer (score 4):

The following example could be used as a starting point:

```
    public static void CopyFiles(string url, string listTitle, string srcFolder,string destFolder)
    {
        using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
        {
            //context.Credentials = credentials;


            var srcList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
            var qry = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            qry.FolderServerRelativeUrl = string.Format("/{0}", srcFolder);
            var srcItems = srcList.GetItems(qry);
            context.Load(srcItems, icol => icol.Include(i => i.FileSystemObjectType, i => i["FileRef"], i => i.File));
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var item in srcItems)
            {
                switch (item.FileSystemObjectType)
                {
                    case FileSystemObjectType.Folder:
                        var destFolderUrl = ((string)item["FileRef"]).Replace(srcFolder,destFolder);
                        CreateFolder(context.Web,destFolderUrl);
                        break;
                    case FileSystemObjectType.File:
                        var destFileUrl = item.File.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(srcFolder, destFolder);
                        item.File.CopyTo(destFileUrl, true);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    } 

    private static Folder CreateFolder(Web web, string folderUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderUrl))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Folder Url could not be empty");

        var folder = web.Folders.Add(folderUrl);
        web.Context.Load(folder);
        web.Context.ExecuteQuery();
        return folder;
    }
```

Usage

```
CopyFiles("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/", "Order Documents", "Archive", "Archive 2014");
```

Key points:

- It is assumed that destination folders do not exist

Answer (score 0):

If you do not insist on preserving some metadata (created date, created by etc.) you can copy files using file explorer.

Or if it is only one-time task, try Sharegate (trial) to move the files.

Comment: OP is asking for a solution using CSOM.